# AngularJS calendar with heatmap

Tags: gratis, calendar, angularjs, heatmap

I am looking for an AngularJS calendar, with heatmap features.

Something that looks like this

[image: Screenshot of example calendar, with days colored in green, yellow, orange, and red.]

while supporting standard AngularJS calendar functionality.

I would like to be able to toggle the heatmap functionality, if possible.

Must be gratis, for commercial use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One that I found that to my understanding uses Angular JS and has a somewhat similar layout as your image is called, "Cal Heatmap AngularJS Directive" which uses this JS library, "cal-heatmap". Both are open-source and available on GitHub. The layout is kind of different to the image above but has the same concept. It doesn't have the histogram on the top/left side and doesn't show the s,m,t,w,etc. but those I believe those can be added without much hardship. It also looks like the same library GitHub uses for profile activity.

## [Cal Heatmap AngularJS Directive](https://github.com/shekhargulati/angular-cal-heatmap-directive)

> This is an AngularJS directive for cal-heatmap

#### [Cal Heatmap](http://cal-heatmap.com/)

> Cal-Heatmap is a javascript module to create a calendar heatmap.
>
> [image: Cal Heatmap no heat]
>
> [image: Cal Heatmap w/ heat]

Comment: I also found that D3Js offers the same thing. See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318